# get all the data of a string array c# (Unity)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Hi guys i need help about getting the data of my string array here is my code :

```
string playerwinnopairboth = "P  ";
string bankerwinnopairboth = "B  ";
string tienopairboth = "T  ";
string bankerwinplayerpairnopair = "BP ";
string bankerwinbankerpairnopair = "BB ";
string playerwinbankerpairnopair = "PB ";
string playerwinplayerpairnopair = "PP ";
string tieplayerpairnopair = "TP ";

string s1 = "";
string s2 = "";
string s3 = "";
string s4 = "";

if (gametable_no == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list.Count; i++)
    {
        s1 += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list[i].r;
        s1 += ",";
    }
    string[] newChars = s1.Split(',');

    if (newChars == playerwinnopairboth)
     {
         o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_player_bigline-01";
         NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
     }
    if (newChars == bankerwinnopairboth)
     {
         o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_banker_bigline-01";
         NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
     }
}
```

Okay i will explain now every line of code.

This line of code :

```
if (gametable_no == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list.Count; i++)
        {
            s1 += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list[i].r;
            s1 += ",";
        }
        string[] newChars = s1.Split(',');
     }
```

will have an output like this if i use a `foreach(string allchar in newChars){Debug.Log(allchars);}`:

> P  ,
>
> B  ,
>
> P B,
>
> B P,
>
> BPP,
>
> PB ,
>
> P  ,
>
> P  ,

its normal output without split is this :

> Gametable 1 History = P  ,B  ,P B,B P,BPP,PB,P  , P  ,

What i am trying to do here is that i need to get all of `string[] newChar` values and have a condition something like this

```
if (newChars == playerwinnopairboth)
{
    o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_player_bigline-01";
    NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
}
if (newChars == bankerwinnopairboth)
{
    o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_banker_bigline-01";
    NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
}
```

and output it something like this

*Legend: x = Player Win, o = Banker Win, xo = Player Win Banker Pair = ox = Banker Win Player Pair, xXx = Player Win No Pair Blayer Pair;*

So in my output above i have

> P  ,
>
> B  ,
>
> P B,

which means my output on my scoreboard must be

X

O

xXx

Like that.

What is happening there is the output i want is not happening . Can someone help me please.

If i am not clear please just comment down and i will edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: here `if (newChars == playerwinnopairboth)` you comare a string array against a single string. try a foreach loop over `newChars` and compare it against your target strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach (string allchars in newChars)
        {
            if (allchars.Contains(playerwinnopairboth))
            {
                //o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_player_bigline-01";
                //NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
                Debug.Log("PLAYER WIN NO PAIR BOTH");
            }
            if (allchars.Contains(bankerwinnopairboth))
            {
                Debug.Log("BANKERWIN NO PAIR BOTH");
            }
        }
```

What i did is this